# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: nodejs

El error me manda específicamente a esta linea. soy un poco new con esto de nodejs, y por supuesto que el formulario envia los datos correctamente a la Base de datos

```
//REGISTER
app.post('/Register',[
    check('EmailR')
        .normalizeEmail()
        .isEmail().withMessage('Email is Invalid')
        .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Field cannot be Empty')
        .custom((value, {req}) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                User.findOne({EmailR: req.body.EmailR}, function(err, user){
                    if(err) {
                        reject(new Error('Server Error'))
                    }
                    if(Boolean(user)) {
                        reject(new Error('E-mail already in use'))
                    }
                    resolve(true)
                });
            });
        }),
    check('PasswordR')
        .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Password Field Cannot be Empty')
        .isLength({min: 6, max:64}).withMessage('Minimum 8 to 64 Character')
        .matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=.\\-_*])([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&+=*.\\-_]){8,}$").withMessage('Minimum allow a number, a lowercase, a uppercase, and a special character')
], function (req,res) {
    let errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors){
        res.status(500).json({msg: 'Data cannot not send'})
    }else{
        res.send('Account Successful Create');
    }
    let body = req.body;
    let {EmailR,PasswordR} = body;
    let data = new User({
        EmailR,
        PasswordR: bcrypt.hashSync(PasswordR,15),
    })
    data.save()
        .then(item => {
            if (item){
                return res.send("Register Successful");
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (err){
                return res.status(400).send("unable to Register Account");
            }
        });
})
```

aqui una foto del mensaje de error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZADO**
ya resubi el código completo como podras ver en el codigo, para el registro de mis usuarios estoy usando express-validator  para validar que el email este correcto y que el password siga un correcto patrón de mayúscula minúsculas y símbolo y determinado mínimo de carácter, ahora me pregunto si la parte donde esta el  `res.status(500).json` pueda estar el problema?

Comment: Falta más código del que aportas, es probable que en tu lógica tengas otra llamada al método `send()` que no nos muestras aquí. Tal vez antes de ese código de `data.save()` o tal vez después del mismo. ¿Podrías mostrar el código de la función middleware completo? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Eso error pasa cuando después de un haber mandado (`send`) una respuesta al cliente, se encuentra con otra llamada que intenta volverlo a hacer. En este caso particular no me queda claro por qué te sale el error ya que en teoría nunca se ejecutan tus dos `send`.

Lo que puedes hacer para asegurarte de que solo se ejecute uno de ellos es terminar la ejecución de la función con un `return`.

```
 data.save()
        .then(item => {
            if (item){
                return res.send("Register Successful");
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (err){
                return res.status(400).send("unable to Register Account");
            }
        });
})
```

Con eso debería bastar para asegurarte de no hacer múltiples envíos al cliente y que no te salga el error

Comment: bueno amigo ya eso de los return , lo había probado ya  técnicamente yo tampoco se en especifico porque sale ese error